# Как нормализовать только ненулевые значения в определенных колонках в StandardScaler?

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, обработка-данных

Как нормализовать только ненулевые значения в определенных колонках?

Мой код:

```
# set params for normalization
COLUMNS_TO_NORMALIZE = ['a', 'b', 'c']

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()

# get index of null values
null_values = X_train[COLUMNS_TO_NORMALIZE].isnull()

# perform standard scalar on only non-NaN values
X_train[COLUMNS_TO_NORMALIZE][~null_values] = sc.fit_transform(X_train[COLUMNS_TO_NORMALIZE][~null_values])
```

Не меняет значения, а возвращает те же, что и были.

Comment: А `Pandas` вас разве не предупреждал, что это "операция над копией"? )  Только через `.loc` надо, двое квадратных скобок не работают в присваивании.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
mask = X_train[COLUMNS_TO_NORMALIZE].isna().any(axis=1)
vals = X_train.loc[~mask, COLUMNS_TO_NORMALIZE]

X_train.loc[~mask, COLUMNS_TO_NORMALIZE] = \
    pd.DataFrame(sc.fit_transform(vals), 
                 index=vals.index, 
                 columns=COLUMNS_TO_NORMALIZE)
```